# mysql like operator on integer giving me much better results than = operator

Tags: mysql

this is the indexes on tblNewsToCity:

[image]

I have this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   `tblnews` 
       INNER JOIN `tblnewstocity` 
               ON `tblnews`.`id` = `tblnewstocity`.`fkid` 
WHERE  `tblnewstocity`.`city` = '233' 
       AND `tblnews`.`id` != '1771' 
ORDER  BY `tblnews`.`id` DESC 
LIMIT  3 offset 0
```

which is running slow [image]

but if i am changing  `tblnewstocitycity = 233`  to: `tblnewstocitycity like 233`

I am getting this good results:
[image]

would love to understand why? what Am i missing? why the first query not running good as the second when the second uses the like operator on integers when it should be even slower

Comment: Are you sure it is running fast? Or are you running the 2 queries one after the other? Maybe if you ran it in separate sessions, you might see that performance is more or less the same.

Comment: yes pretty sure tested it multiple times one after another and vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has several options to execute that query:

- look for ALL rows with `tblnewstocity.city = '233'` by using the index, do the join and order by the id. It has to check all rows given by the index, because the first 3 don't have to have the largest `tblnews.id`.
- go through `tblnews` in the `order by`-order (from the end), do the join, and look for the FIRST 3 rows that happens to have the right `city`-value. It can stop after having found 3 rows, as there cannot be larger `tblnews.id`.

It depends on your data which way is faster. If you have e.g. only 2 rows that fit your `index`-conditions (and the join), the first one will be faster, because it just have to check a handful of rows, while the second query would have to check the whole table to realize there are only 2. If e.g. all rows would have `city = 233`, the first query would have to find all (by index, but it will still be all), order them and take the first 3, while the second query will only have to test the first 3 rows, because the are already ordered.

A realistic distribution will lie somewhere in between these possibilities. MySQL has to guess. It guessed that the index (for `=`) will give you only a little number of rows, so it took option 1. `like` will make MySQL trust the index less, so it will prefer the second option, which, luckily, was the faster one. But it could have gone the other way too, try e.g. `like` and `=` with a value that has no city (well, depending on your mysql server version, the optimizer might check it and might not fall for that, so maybe test it with a value that would only give a handfull of rows without the limit.

Long story short: there are two solutions for that:

- either replace `INNER JOIN tblnewstocity` with `straight_join tblnewstocity`, this will force mysql to take the second way (but of course risking slow execution for the counter examples)
- or add a proper index: `tblnewstocity (city, fkid)` should take care of the problem. You might have to change `ORDER  BY tblnews.id DESC` to `ORDER  BY tblnewstocity.fkid DESC`, which is equivalent because `tblnewstocity.fkid = tblnews.id` according to the `join`-condition, and mysql should realize this on its own, but you never know...

Comment: I think `fkid_2` is index for `(city, fkid)`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza No, it is in the wrong order. Although a clever mysql could probably still use it to optimize the join-part.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure regarding the `LIKE` issue, but you should include the filter in the `JOIN`

```
SELECT * 
FROM   `tblnews` 
INNER JOIN `tblnewstocity` 
   ON `tblnews`.`id` = `tblnewstocity`.`fkid` 
  AND `tblnews`.`id` != '1771' 
  AND `tblnewstocity`.`city` = '233'      
ORDER  BY `tblnews`.`id` DESC 
LIMIT  3 offset 0
```

Comment: thanks didnt think of it, but still same explain results

Comment: Those index are on tblnews or tblnewstocity or both? not sure about that display you put.

Comment: sorry this indxes are on tblnewstocity the explain show me that the problem is in this table so I didnt show the other tables indexes

Comment: can you show me both  create table? I m not sure how read those index. And the order is on tblnews so is also important

Comment: Ok, i realize you can put the city condition also in the join. check the explain plan.

Comment: same results :( its some legacy website that I am trying to fix some slowness maybe its because the tblnewstocity is myisam I am changing to innodb